# Switching a voltage higher than Vgs MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, high-voltage, mosfet-driver

In order to drive a voltage higher than the M1 Vgs, I think that limiting the Vgs voltage with a zener diode could be a good idea. It will be only switched once per minute. By this I mean that high frequencies are not needed.

M1 - main MOSFET.
D1 - used to protect Vgs overvoltage.
R1 - used to charge GS (to switch off M1 if M2 is open).
R2 - used to limit the current through the zener.

M2 - used to drive M2 gate.
R4 - used to pull-down switch off M2 during 3V3 signal is open drain.

Could be the following circuit a good aproach?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQIobZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What supply voltage range is it to accommodate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zener diode is a pretty much standard solution for this, it should work fine.

Only major issue I can see in your schematic is M2, it requires too high gate voltage to be used with 3V3 control (threshold voltage of <4 V). But with another model transistor, no problem.

I'd use a slightly lower voltage zener diode, 12V or so, to have some extra margin if maximum Vgs of M1 is 20V. You could also use a slightly higher value of R2, to get a bit lower current and thus use a smaller (lower power rating) resistor for that.

Comment: Related to M2 you are right. I chose "one MOSFET" and I forgot to delete the reference. It was my fault.